# Can we install C gems in ruby 2.7.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-c-extension

I just upgraded by ruby to 2.7.0.

And I tried to install the ibm_db gem in windows platform. Installation works fine. When I try to use the gem(like require 'ibm_db') I get the following error

```
LoadError (126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ibm_db-5.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mswin32/rb2x/i386/ibm_db.so)
```

I have faced this type of error in ruby 2.6 also but when I have set RUBY_DLL_PATH to the ddl which the gem uses it is solved.

But in ruby 2.7 even after setting this variable I get the following error.

Can anyone please help in solving this? ( I have one more doubt:- c gems are supported in ruby 2.7)

Comment: Your question in the title is: can x be done? And the answer is yes, but this differs from your question in the post. I recommend altering your post title so it more accurately reflects your question. (you want to know how to fix a problem, not if something is possible)

Comment: Many gems have other dependencies which may need to be installed first. For example MySQL requires MySQL's dynamic libraries (`.dll`, `.so` or `.bundle` depending on your OS) to be present, and most often the development headers as well so they can be linked against. Check this gem's documentation closely for installation requirements.

Comment: Also worth noting you might want to use 2.7.1 which contains bugfixes from the 2.7.0 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the binary was pointed to ruby 2.6 binary. So replace it with the latest ruby 2.7 binary and then everything works fine.

Thanks,
Akhil

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `ibm_db` gem currently does not support Ruby 2.7 yet. The newest Ruby version they support is Ruby 2.6.x.

There is a pull request at https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb/pull/105 which might add support for Ruby 2.7 though.